# Monospaced font with even more equality between the letters

Tags: font-recommendation

Is there a font where all the letters follow something like a fixed grid? Like a monospaced font, but even more equality between the letters. Everything should be in one line.

I marked in the picture what bothers me.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Most professional fonts have these *optical adjustments* you don't like. If you are wondering *why* they exist, you can check out [this article from Hoefler&Co](https://www.typography.com/blog/typographic-illusions) and [this series of articles from OH no Type Company](https://ohnotype.co/blog/tagged/teaching).

There are a lot of free amateur fonts that *don't* have these adjustments and are strictly based on a simple geometry. For example have a look at a site like [DaFont](https://www.dafont.com/). More specifically you could browse the [Basic > Fixed width](https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=503) category.

For example does the font [Zector](https://www.dafont.com/zector.font?back=theme) seem to live up to your requirements.

[image]

If you have some basic vector construction skills, you could easily construct these kind of letters yourself. The real time consuming part of font design is making all the optical adjustments and especially the kerning for each pair of characters. If you are just making a monospaced font which rigidly follows a grid, you can skip that.

[image]

When you get to the diagonal strokes, you will however encounter some dilemmas regarding how to make them follow the grid. I'll leave that up to you to explore.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

1. Get one which mimics a sparse dot matrix or segmented led display
2. Make your own with a font editor. It's very easy because you will have no typographic finesses. You can start from empty template. Or modify a free to use free to modify (see the license) monospace font.